# Adding a Class to first item in a list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ((location.search.indexOf('page=') < 0) || (location.search.indexOf('page=1') > 0) {
    if (($('select.sort-by option:selected').text() == "Most Popular") || ($('select.sort-by option:selected').text() == "Best Selling")) {
        $('li.collection-indv-product:first').css('border', '#ffc000 solid 10px');
        $("li.collection-indv-product:first").find('div.collection-product').before('<div style="background:#ffc000;text-align:left;padding: 0 0 5px 5px;color:#353535;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;">Customer Favorite in {{collection.title}}</div>');
    }
}
```

I'm having issues with this.

I want to add a border around the first item in the list on our category pages, but only on the first page, not the following pages. Am I doing this right? I can't get it to work and it seems like this would work.

Comment: Is page 1 page=1 or page=0 ?

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of the markup you are trying to match? And are you trying to match the first-child or the first item found period?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use `parseInt()` to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at what you might be trying to do, see below. Also, I would remove the inline style from your DIV and give it a class, moving the styles to a stylesheet. It's much cleaner and easier to maintain down the road.

That being said, here is a suggestion:

```
    $(function () {
        function getPage() {
            var query = location.search;
            if (query != '') {
                // this gets 'page' anywhere in the querystring
                var qs = query.substr(1).split('&');
                for (k in qs) {
                    if (qs[k].indexOf('page') == 0) {
                        var page = qs[k].split('=')[1];
                        return page;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;    // page wasn't found
        }

        if (getPage() == '1') {
            var sort = $('select.sort-by :selected').val();
            if (sort == 'Most Popular' || sort == 'Best Selling') {
                // use .first() and chaining for performance
                var li = $('li.collection-indv-product').first();
                li.css('border', '#ffc000 solid 10px')
                    .find('div.collection-product').before('<div style="background:#ffc000;text-align:left;padding: 0 0 5px 5px;color:#353535;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;"/>').text('Customer Favorite in {{collection.title}}');
                ;
            }
        }
    });
```